# How to install xmlgawk in MSYS2

Tags: xml-parsing, msys2

Can anyone tell me how to install the XML gawk in MSYS2? My knowledge are poor. I tried to find but it's to difficult for me to understand.

Comment: What specific problem have you run into? A description of what you have done, edited into your question, would be most welcome.

Comment: Google says `xmlgawk` just calls `gawk -ixmllib`, does that command work for you?